# Generate function using /dev/random showing Segmentation fault (core dumped) error when called

Tags: c, file, random

The following code is supposed to be run from terminal so you should be able to choose different functions by just typing the name of a function and providing it with arguments (for example ./program generate dog 5 20 should generate 5 lines each with 20 characters and save them into the the file called dog). The other functions that you can see here may be a part of a problem that's why I'm including them although the problem itself occurs when I try to generate things. As you can see other functions are just declarations now mostly cuz I wanted to test if the first one was working correctly before going to others.

I was thinking that maybe I should write something that would actually take data from console input and put them directly into what's called "a" and "b" but if there is a problem with the function itself it won't help at all.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>



void generate(const char *str, int a, int b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int if_generate = (strcmp("generate", argv[1])==0);
    
    
    if (if_generate){
    generate(argv[2], argv[3], argv[4]);
}else{
printf("wrong function name");
}


}

void generate(const char *str, int a, int b){

    int n,m;
    int myFile = open(str, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR |S_IWUSR);
    int randomiser = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
    char bufor[b+1];
    for(n=0; n<a; n++){
    for (m=0; m<b; m++){
        read (randomiser, &bufor, 1);
        write (myFile, &bufor, 1);
    }
        write(myFile, "\n", 1);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please pay attention to compiler warnings: `argv[3], argv[4]` are not `int` type and cannot be passed to `a`, `b` of `void generate(const char *str, int a, int b)`. Moreover you must check `if(argc >= 5)` first.

Comment: done. only parts connected directly to said function remain

Comment: You need to use `atoi(argv[3]), atoi(argv[4])` to convert them to int

Comment: @WeatherVane so my idea that i need to put them directly into a and b using additional code should help?

Comment: Please see the @Barmar [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64667829/generate-function-using-dev-random-showing-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-err#comment114342030_64667829).

Comment: yeah, it appeared right after i finished writing that one

Comment: so basically if i convert them AND check for number of argc everything else is correct?

Comment: Is the file supposed to be a text file? You're writing binary data to the file.

Comment: `&bufor` should just be `bufor`. Arrays automatically decay to pointers when used as function arguments.

Comment: Why do you declare the size of `bufor` to be `[b+1]`? You only write 1 byte into it. It doesn't even need to be an array.

Comment: @Barmar you are definitely correct - size of bufor was just something that remained after my previous approach to the problem didnt even notice it

Comment: thank you very much @Barmar and WeatherVane. Thanks to information you provided i was able to make it work finally. Huge huge thanks

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Using information provided by @Barmar and @WeatherVane i changed the code a bit and it worked as intended.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int if_generate = argc>=5 && strcmp("generate", argv[1])==0;
    
    
    if (if_generate){
    int x,y;
    x=atoi(argv[3]);
    y=atoi(argv[4]);
    generate(argv[2], x, y);
}else{
printf("wrong function name");
}


}
```

that was all that was required for this to work.